# Why is there output from this code?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I wanted to know why the output of *this* `code` is nothing? Is it something related to the use of `SIZE` in the `for` loop expression?

**CODE**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int array[6] = {4, 5, 6, 10, -1, 0};
#define SIZE (sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))
int main() {
    int i;  
    for (i= -1; i< SIZE; ++i)  printf("%d", array[i+1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried printing out `SIZE` to see exactly how many times your loop is running?

Comment: is sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]) always valid? Division by zero?

Comment: @Arc676 That won't solve anything. SIZE will be 6 but the loop is still not running, because the size itself is not the issue...

Comment: @Lundin Yes I am aware of that now

Comment: @bub Yes. It is valid. And `sizeof(int)` will always be greater than 1.

Comment: in that case yes it will

Answer (score 10):

```
for (i= -1; i< SIZE; ++i)  printf("%d", array[i+1]);
```

Instead , initialize `i` to `0` in your loop -

```
for (i= 0; i< SIZE; ++i)  printf("%d", array[i]);
```

Reason why you get nothing output ,*because loop doesn't iterate* due to comparison between signed and unsigned integer (*conversion of* `-1` *to* `unsigned int` *and results in a very large value , therefore condition is false*) .

Comment: thank you very much, It was an exam question asking for the output of this code and I just didn't realize why the answer is that the output is nothing. now I completely understood.@ameyCU

Answer (score 5):

The result of the `sizeof` operator is always the type `size_t` which is guaranteed to be an unsigned integer larger or equal to `unsigned int`.

Therefore the resulting type of your whole `SIZE` macro is `size_t`, an unsigned int type.

The iterator `i` is however declared as a plain `int` which is signed and contains a negative value.

In the expression `i< SIZE`, there is an implicit type conversion of `i` to the same type as `SIZE` ("the usual arithmetic conversions"). Since it is a negative number, it will end up as a very large unsigned number. The condition evaluates to false and the `for` loop is therefore never executed.

Comment: thank you very much, It was an exam question asking for the output of this code and I just didn't realize why the answer is that the output is nothing. now I completely understood.@Lundin

Comment: "_Since it is a negative number, it will end up as a very large unsigned number_" -- Which will be equal to `UINT_MAX` in this case, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes. The standard states that the conversion from signed to unsigned is done by repeatedly adding one value higher than the maximum value of the unsigned type, until the value is in range of the unsigned type. `-1 + UINT_MAX+1 == UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 3):

In your loop

```
for (i= -1; i< SIZE; ++i)
```

the check `i < SIZE` is evaluated as unsigned, that means `MAX_UINT < 6`, that is `false`.

Then your `for` doesn't iterate.

Use the loop below instead

```
for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)  printf("%d", array[i]);
```

An alternative, not recommended, could be

```
for (i= -1; i< (int)SIZE-1; i++)  printf("%d", array[i+1]);
```

Comment: is it because `-1` is stored as `0xFFFFFFFF` ( 2's complement of -1 )?

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, Exactly!

Comment: Tnx but why when we compare them `0xFFFFFFFF` is evaludated and not -1?

Comment: @Ehsan because of there `sizeof` return `size_t`, that is `unsigned`. Then the compiler do an implicit conversion of `i` to `unsigned int`. Then `i` will be `4294967295`

Comment: thank you very much, It was an exam question asking for the output of this code and I just didn't realize why the answer is that the output is nothing. now I completely understood.@LPs